# Wordpress + Contact Form 7: One or more fields have an error (treating first field as empty even when it is filled)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am asking this question after I found the answer so that no one else spends much time debugging it in case the same happened to them (my googling didn't yield many useful results)

In short, some of my CF7 forms suddenly stopped submitting and it was giving me the orange error about empty fields. It was also flagging the first field in the form as being empty even though it was filled.

Nothing was being logged in Flamingo. Recaptcha was working properly. I attempted to fix the permalinks. Nothing was fixing the issue.

Turns out it was a problem with how some field codes were written inside the HTML of the form. The type of error will be unique, but in general, make sure your fields are written properly and that there are no commented parts in the form HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was as follows:

I was using the following code for some select fields:
[image: error code]

And to be written properly they had to be as such:
[image: correct code]

That was it for me.